# Navigating or Routing

Tags: angularjs

I have two htmls and their respective controllers.Also i have placed routing condition. My task is when user clicks on Search button after providing the project name, i need to route the page with project name parameter. I am using $location in the controller search function, but it returns nothing. What is the mistake: 
Here is the code

Index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->

    <!-- Include the AngularJS library -->
    <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="EAPApp">
     <div >
        <h1>Enterprise Application Portfolio</h1>
    </div>

    <div ng-view ng-controller="MainController"></div>


    <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/ProjectDetailsController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/SearchController.js"></script>

    <!-- Directives -->
    <!--<script src="js/directives/appinfo.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives/Search.js"></script>-->


</body>
</html>


<!--<div  ng-controller="MainController">
       <div >
           <div ng-repeat="app in Applications">
               <appinfo info="app"></appinfo>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>-->
```

ProjectSearch:

```
<br />
<label>Search Application</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="applicationname" />
<br />
<button ng-click="Search()">Search</button>
```

ProjectDetails.html:

```
<div  ng-controller="ProjectDetailsController">
      <div >
          <p> Into Project Details</p>
              <appinfo info="app"></appinfo>

      </div>
  </div>
```

SearchController.js:

```
app.controller('SearchController', ['$scope', function ($scope, $location)
   {
    $scope.applicationname = "";

    $scope.ApplicationName = function (applicationname) {
        $scope.applicationname = applicationname;
    };

    $scope.Search = function () {
        //$location.path("http://localhost:35963/index.html#//Project/ARMS");


        var test = $location.url();
        console.log(test);
        console.log("absurl");
        console.log($location.absUrl());
        console.log("protocol");
        console.log($location.protocol);


    };

  }]);
```

ProjectDetailsController.js:

```
angular.module("mainModule", [])
 .controller("ProjectDetailsController", function ($scope, $location, $routeParams)
  {
    $scope.Application =
            {
                ApplicationName: 'ARMS',
                ApplicationID: 1,
                ApplicationStatus: 'Open',
                ApplicationOwner: 'Prasanna',
                ApplicationGroup: 'Finance'
            };

});
```

MainController.js:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope, $location) {
    {
        $scope.Applications = [
        {
        ApplicationName: 'XX',
        ApplicationID: 1,
        ApplicationStatus: 'Open',
        ApplicationOwner: 'XXX',
        ApplicationGroup: 'Finance'
        },
        {
        ApplicationName: 'XYZ',
        ApplicationID: 2,
        ApplicationStatus: 'Open',
        ApplicationOwner: 'Lakshmi',
        ApplicationGroup: 'MFG'
        },
        {
        ApplicationName: 'ABC',
        ApplicationID: 3,
        ApplicationStatus: 'Open',
        ApplicationOwner: 'Prasanna',
        ApplicationGroup: 'MFG'
        },
        {
        ApplicationName: 'QWE',
        ApplicationID: 4,
        ApplicationStatus: 'Open',
        ApplicationOwner: 'Prasanna',
        ApplicationGroup: 'MFG'
        }
        ]
        }
}]);
```

Comment: where did you put the **ProjectSearch** part? Could you post routings too?